# Understanding Houdini terrain generation math

Tags: math, houdini

I am trying to understand how [Houdini](https://www.sidefx.com/products/houdini/) generates terrain, but I cannot find the relevant documentation. For example, I am looking for a mathematical description of the algorithms used to calculate terrain erosion and animal path determination.

Comment: Are you asking specifically how one piece of (I believe) closed-source software does its stuff ?  Or how that kind of software does that kind of thing ?  Either way, probably way to broad for a question here.  Probably off-topic too on the grounds that you ask for references to off-site resources. Have you exhausted Internet resources on topics such as *procedural generation of terrain* ?

Comment: Mine was more of a general curiosity, so a paper like this shoulod do the work: https://web.mit.edu/cesium/Public/terrain.pdf Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the implementation of the erosion nodes within Houdini.

There are 4 terrain erosion nodes in Houdini 17.5:

- [HeightField Erode Hydro](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/heightfield_erode_hydro.html)
- [HeightField Erode Precipitation](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/heightfield_erode_precipitation.html)
- [HeightField Erode Thermal](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/heightfield_erode_thermal.html)
- [HeightField Erode](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/heightfield_erode.html) - a convenience node that runs all the previous erode nodes

Each one of the nodes above is implemented by a [Geometry (SOP) network](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/index.html). You can navigate/inspect  these node networks in the [Network editor](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/network/navigate.html).

The screenshots below show an eroded terrain with the top level geometry network that generates it and 2 example nodes you will find inside each of the top level nodes.

#### Eroded Terrain with Geometry Subnetwork

[image: Eroded Terrain with Top Level Geometry Network]

#### OpenCL Node

The [OpenCL Node](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/opencl.html) allows you to write code to implement the node with OpenCL.

[image: OpenCL Node within Erode Hydro]

#### Attribute Wrangle Node

The [Attribute Wrangle Node](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/attribwrangle.html) contains VEX code that can read and write Houdini geometry attributes.

[image: VEX Node within Erode Hydro]